# Can objects instantiated within a static method be overwritten if the method is called on multiple threads?

Tags: c#, static, instance-variables, thread-safety

If you retrieve an instance variable within a static method based on a parameter supplied to the static method, is it possible the instance variable can get stepped on if the static method is called at exactly the same time by different callers?
The method I am calling is defined below and I am wondering if the instance variable invoice can be corrupted... any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static void SendInvoiceReceipt(int invoiceId, string recipientEmailAddress)
{
    var invoice = ObjectFactory.GetInvoiceDAL().GetInvoiceByInvoiceId(invoiceId);

    var htmlBody = BuildHtmlInvoiceReceipt(invoice);
    var txtBody = BuildTextInvoiceReceipt(invoice);

    UtilitiesManager.Emails.EmailUtil.Send(SiteConfigUtilities.GetSMTPServer(),
            "referral@realtors.net", recipientEmailAddress, String.Empty,
            "Payment Receipt", htmlBody, txtBody);
}
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate tags (C#) in the title. Just leave them in the tags.

Comment: Given John's (correct) answer, maybe you might want to explain what error you're seeing.

Comment: A client recieved a receipt containing the invoice data of not only their purchase, but also the purchase of someone else. The payment took place about 8 seconds apart, so I am kind of just grasping that this may have something to do with invoice object being instantiated within a static method.  But according to John's response (thanks by the way) this doesn't sound like a possibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`invoice` is a local variable (not an "instance variable"). It is allocated on the stack, and each thread has its own stack. There is no way for another thread to affect it.